# Coin battery for powering the RTC while MCU power down: is safe for ATEX ZONE 2 or DIV2 in hazardous environment? The Box is heavy duty IP67 sealed

Tags: batteries, safety, rtc, hazardous-areas, functional-safety

I wish to use RTC which keep powered by a coin battery (i.e. CR1225) while disconnected from +5V power. The box is heavy aluminum diecast with IP67 sealed. I was concerned about using coin batteries (non-recharagable) within Div2 or Atex Zone 2 hazardous environment.

I note most regulations related to the large or high-powered battery which does not apply to small coin cell batteries.

I also note many shipping restrictions about lithium batteries.

One solution I can think of is to use a supercapacitor. However, I would like to know what regulations in Canada and the USA are related to small battery use in the hazardous environment.

Comment: It’s been a while since I’ve looked at the relevant standards, but from what I can recall primary batteries are allowed. I’ve also seen many ex products where this is the case. A supercap is a viable solution if the unit is normally powered externally.